# which specific conditions could cause a db4o's native query transformation bug?

Tags: c#, .net, db4o, nativequery

This fails:

```
var results = container.Query<SomeClass>(s =>
    s.Field == value && s.AnEnumField != SomeEnum.AnEnumValue
);
Assert.AreEqual(1, results.Count);
```

But this doesn't:

```
Predicate<SomeClass> matches = s => 
    s.Field == value && s.AnEnumField != SomeEnum.AnEnumValue;
var results = container.Query<SomeClass>(s => matches(s));
Assert.AreEqual(1, results.Count);
```

The different in the tests clearly demonstrates the issue happens only when db4o does the expression transformation, as calling a method prevents that. The value checked in the test, is the exact value (no case differences), as the test inserts it first.

Any special conditions where the db4o transformations has bugs with those queries? maybe with .net enums?

---

I have narrowed it down, and my example above didn't include the troublesome bit. Doesn't have to do with the enum field, but with "value" in the above expression.

Specifically the issue happens when the query includes someInstance.Field for the value, like:

```
var results =
container.Query<SomeClass>(s =>
   s.Field == someInstance.Field && s.AnEnumField != SomeEnum.AnEnumValue
); 
Assert.AreEqual(1, results.Count);
```

Comment: If you are sure it's a bug you could report it in their forums.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't submitting it as a bug as I didn't have an isolated reprod of the bug. Reaching that point, required to figure out the conditions that caused the issue / added in an answer. I posted the bug with the full reprod in here: http://tracker.db4o.com/browse/COR-2158.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got to reproduce it in an isolated project (after narrowing it down more in the main project).

Conditions under which this particular bug occur are very specific. Given the last sample code I posted in the question:

- SomeClass is a subclass of another class. Field is defined in the base class
- someInstance in the sample code, must be a subclass of the same base class

Comment: If there's no report of this on http://tracker.db4o.com please go ahead and create one (it's public)

Comment: @German I did near the time I posted this answer, link in the comments of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Well I didn't tried out your code, but to me that looks like a bug, probably in the native-query optimizer. The first one it a typical native query which should be optimization. And I guess that there something goes wrong.
The second query probably cannot be optimized, because is a unusual way to write a query. In that case db4o just calls the closure/delegate and therefore produces the right result.

To work around this bug I would recommend you to use [LINQ](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/net35/reference/Content/basics/querying/linq.htm). Include the 'Db4objects.Db4o.Linq.dll'-assembly in your project, add the 'Db4objects.Db4o.Linq'-namespace and write the queries. For example like this:

```
var result = from SomeClass s in container
               where s.Field == value && s.AnEnumField != SomeEnum.AnEnumValue
               select s;
Assert.AreEqual(1, results.Count);
```

I would recommend you anyway to use LINQ instead of native queries. LINQ is much more powerful and a 'standard'-API.

For the original issue: Maybe post this as a small example program as an bug in the [db4o-bugtracker](http://tracker.db4o.com). (Maybe you have register [here](http://www.db4o.com/Users/register.aspx) to get an account for the bugtracker, I'm not sure about that.)

Comment: Hi Gamlor thanks for the answer. The native query optimization is what I was referring about with the expression transformation, so the second version was done specifically to confirm the issue only happens when the optimizations takes place. I already have a workaround in place, which was to move to SODA / which is the best option, as it's still too easy to get unoptimized queries and thus a serious performance impact on the applications when using both native queries and the LINQ provider. I guess I was being lazy by not doing the last step / reprod in a separate project and submit the bug.

Comment: fyi you're right this bug doesn't happen in the LINQ version (confirmed with a quick test).

Comment: As I feared, I can't get it to reproduce in a separate project. I'm not so worried about the specific bit of code that I fixed, but what could cause such issue / to make sure we don't have the problem elsewhere ... since it's a pain, because it' a silent error.

Comment: I got to reproduce it, but after narrowing down the issue / kind of the reason for the question :). See my answer.